# Button.center not working on all screens in Swift 3 / 4

Tags: ios, swift, button, swift3, center

I created a "more" button in my app, and a cool animation when we focus the button. It's working very well on iPhone 6 but not on 6S plus or 5s for example.

This is my button and my constraints :

[image]

I create a backgroundView that I animate when I focus the button:

```
func createBackgroundEffet(_ backgroundView: UIView, size: Int, buttonFocused: UIButton){
      backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
      backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200 / 255, green: 200 / 255, blue: 200 / 255, alpha: 1)
      backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backgroundView.frame.size.width / 2
      backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
      backgroundView.center = buttonFocused.center
      backgroundView.alpha = 1
      self.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 2)
 }
```

(I set backgroundView.alpha = 1 for the example)

And this the results depending on the screen (on iPhone 6 it's perfectly on the "more" button).

[image]

I think the buttonFocused.center value is the value from the iPhone 6.

What can I do to correct this problem ?

Comment: where do you call this `createBackgroundEffet `?

Comment: In the view didLoad() or awakeFromNib() of the view

Comment: Try call it from `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubview`, in `viewDidLoad` the view have not been layout yet, result in wrong behavior

Comment: It seems to be good with viewDidLayoutSubview but it's not working when I'm on a cell or UICollectionReusableView file ...

Answer (score 0):

you are definetly have some problems with your constraints.

first of all remove all constraints and this constraint
[image]

than assign constraints like this
for top guy:
[image]

and for more button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't do that. The height and width of the picture is not fixed. It's set according to the screen :/

Comment: have you tried to put them to stackviews and use size classes? i think it should help you.